# Whether Sharepoint api use in android studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Whether Sharepoint Api can be communicated with android studio or any communication method to fetch Sharepoint to  mobile device?
example like visual studio

Answer (score 0):

No, cannot use sharepoint directly in android.will be convert to  nodejs or any   ff